# importing an array column to Parse.com

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, import

I have a csv file with array data that I need to import as a class to Parse.com.  My understanding is that arrays need to be in the following format in Parse:

["a","b","c"]

So that's the format all my arrays are in.

The problem is that when I import the file, and prompted to define my schema, my array columns are only given the following options: string, number, and boolean.  "Array" is not presented as an option.  And yet, I know that "array" is an option because when creating a class from scratch, it is presented as a column option.

Just for laughs I tried to import my array column as a string.  But when I pulled the data in my iOS app, it retrieved the array data as a single string and added backslashes(like this: "["\a"\,"\b"\,"\c"]"), and I'm pretty sure that's unusable as an array.

Can anyone help with importing my arrays to Parse, and having Parse recognize and store this data as arrays?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing a .csv file to Parse, it only accepts string, boolean, or number values. **You cannot import an array into Parse from a CSV file.** The only way to do this if you need to upload an array is to have your data in JSON format.